# Annotation and boxplot width after combining ggplotly() with ggplot2 boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, boxplot

I have created a boxplot using `annotate()` in order to display summary statistics and also setting the width of the box plot but when I used `ggplotly()` as you can see both the width and the annotation broke. How can I fix those by using `ggplot2` or only `plotly`?

```
throu<-structure(list(case_id = c("WC4132791", "WC4130879", "WC4128064", 
    "WC4121569", "WC4121568", "WC4130112", "WC4131829", "WC4130841", 
    "WC4130306", "WC4130417", "WC4124741", "WC4130114", "WC4131990", 
    "WC4121986", "WC4128062", "WC4122478", "WC4130337", "WC4125822", 
    "WC4127231", "WC4124761", "WC4129398", "WC4131040", "WC4123072", 
    "WC4131822", "WC4120712", "WC4121978", "WC4130110", "WC4123522", 
    "WC4130307", "WC4122643", "WC4130383", "WC4122248", "WC4122299", 
    "WC4122727", "WC4126769", "WC4131186", "WC4125978", "WC4129089", 
    "WC4121339", "WC4126469", "WC4131800", "WC4125572", "WC4132378", 
    "WC4123345", "WC4130314", "WC4127722", "WC4129978", "WC4131838", 
    "WC4130812", "WC4126953"), throughput_time = c(134.283333333333, 
    93.0756944444445, 83.5340277777778, 67.7833333333333, 65.3069444444444, 
    63.5402777777778, 59.6861111111111, 56.9791666666667, 55.9048611111111, 
    54.3826388888889, 52.6958333333333, 52.5125, 51.1680555555556, 
    50.9520833333333, 50.5402777777778, 49.9291666666667, 49.8201388888889, 
    49.7375, 49.0916666666667, 46.3069444444444, 45.30625, 45.2451388888889, 
    44.9722222222222, 44.8215277777778, 44.8048611111111, 43.0701388888889, 
    42.6840277777778, 42.6576388888889, 42.55, 42.2868055555556, 
    42.2805555555556, 41.9027777777778, 41.7409722222222, 41.6506944444444, 
    41.3527777777778, 40.7305555555556, 40.2861111111111, 40.2159722222222, 
    40.0854166666667, 40.0486111111111, 39.7930555555556, 39.6576388888889, 
    39.4638888888889, 39.4527777777778, 39.3569444444444, 39.3513888888889, 
    39.1854166666667, 39.0791666666667, 39.0743055555556, 39.0055555555556
    )), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")
```

I also have already extracted summary stats in a separate dataframe:

```
    quarts<- structure(list(min = 0, q1 = 7.1515625, median = 11.4881944444444, 
        mean = 12.3112423835125, q3 = 14.8456597222222, max = 93.0756944444445, 
        st_dev = 6.72704434885421, iqr = 7.69409722222222), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L))

p<-ggplot(throu, aes( y=throughput_time)) + 
      geom_boxplot(fill="steelblue", alpha=0.2,width=0.05) +
      annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.05, y = 60, hjust = 0, color = 'gray50',
               label = paste(names(quarts), collapse = '\n')) +
      annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.07, y = 60, hjust = 0,
               label = paste(round(unlist(quarts), 3), collapse = '\n')) +
      xlim(-0.1, 0.1) +
      xlab("")+ylab("Case duration in days")+ theme_classic()+ 
      theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_blank())
    ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout` with `boxgap`;

```
p <- ggplot(throu, aes(x = 0, y=throughput_time)) + 
      geom_boxplot(fill="steelblue", alpha=0.2,width=0.05) +
      annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.05, y = 60, hjust = 0, color = 'gray50',
               label = paste(names(quarts), collapse = '\n')) +
      annotate(geom = 'text', x = 0.07, y = 60, hjust = 0,
               label = paste(round(unlist(quarts), 3), collapse = '\n')) +
      xlim(-0.1, 0.1) +
      xlab("") + ylab("Case duration in days") + 
      theme_classic()

plotly::ggplotly(p) %>% plotly::layout(boxgap=0.93)
```

[image]